# how can i know whether i am using a snapshot version or not

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have created my own repository under my hard disk 
using Apache Server and provided username and password under settings.xml file 
under the M2_HOME

And  when i am running mvn deploy under command prompt its displaying BUILD ERROR 
saying this

```
<distributionManagement>
  <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. --
  <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Please tell me how can i know whether i am using a snapshot version
(I have imported an existing Maven project into Eclipse , i dont know about maven  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to check in the same pom.xml file of the project whether the `<version \>` tag includes the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix. If the ${project.version} is not defined, look for the same tag under the `<parent \>` tag.

Anyway, you are going to have some hard time setting up deployment with no previous knowledge of Maven. I suggest you take a look at [this free PDF guide](https://code.google.com/p/opencookbook/downloads/detail?name=BetterBuildsWithMaven.pdf), which is a pretty good introduction to the tool.

Comment: "this free PDF guide" link is moved. Can you please link the current PDF?